# Select a specific row with additional column that its value is from another column in one table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Suppose I have a table named `users` consist of columns: `user_id`, `user_name`, `user_created_by`.

```
+------------------+----------------------+-------------------+
|    user_id       +      user_name       +  user_created_by  +
+------------------+----------------------+-------------------+
|        1         |        John          |         1         |
|        2         |        Ann           |         1         |
|        3         |        Paul          |         2         |
|        4         |        King          |         2         |
|        5         |        Dirk          |         3         |
+------------------+----------------------+-------------------+
```

The value of `user_created_by` is the `user_id` who created that record. Now, I want to make a query that results one specific row with added column let's say `user_created_by_name` which is the `user_name` of the `user_id` from the `user_created_by`. Suppose we want to get **"Paul"**'s record with who (the name) create it (temporary new column). For ease of understanding this is my expected result:

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
| user_id  |   user_name  |  user_created_by  |  user_created_by_name  |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|    3     |     Paul     |        2          |          Ann           |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

this is my query using codeigniter:

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT *, 
                           (SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_id = user_created_by) 
                              AS "user_created_by_name" FROM users WHERE user_id=3);
```

But my result are:

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
| user_id  |   user_name  |  user_created_by  |  user_created_by_name  |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|    3     |     Paul     |        2          |         NULL           |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: See about JOINs

Comment: i find it hard to believe you get a result with your codeigniter code which you copy/paste here because it has syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You culd use a self join (join the same table two time)  using alias for fere to the tables as different sets of data

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.user_name, a.user_created_by, b.user_name as user_created_by_name
from users a 
inner join user b on a.user_created_by = b.user_id 
where a.user_id  = 3
```

Comment: after just change the a.user_id, a.user_name, a.user_created_by to a.* and add 'WHERE a.user_id = 3' on the end. Finally it works!

Comment: @JONPANTAU  . correct  .  i
I had forgotten that you only wanted the user = 3 .. anyway  .. the suggestion was correct  .. answer updated .

Answer (score 1):

use self join

```
 select u1.user_id, u1.name as user_name,
 u2.user_created_by        
,u2.user_name as createdby  from users u1
 join users u2 on u1.user_id=u2.user_created_by   
 where u1.user_id=3
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
SELECT a.user_id as User_id, 
    a.user_name as Name, 
    b.user_id as Created_by_user_id, 
    b.user_name as Created_by_name
FROM users AS a
INNER JOIN users AS b
ON a.user_id = b.user_created_by
WHERE a.user_id = 3
```

It is called a self-join, which is used when combining two records of the same table.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using a [JOIN](http://www.sql-join.com/).

```
$sql = "SELECT users.user_id, users.user_name,  user_created_by_name.user_name,
        FROM users JOIN users AS user_created_by_name ON users.user_id = user_created_by_name.user_id WHERE users.user_id = 3";

$query=$this->db->query($sql);
```

If you you have users that were not created by another user use a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types) instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT users.user_id, users.user_name, user_created_by_name.user_name,
        FROM users LEFT JOIN users AS user_created_by_name ON users.user_id = users.user_id WHERE user_created_by_name.user_id = 3";

$query=$this->db->query($sql);
```